# std::future hangs with no worker thread

Tags: c++11, asynchronous, std

I'm faced a strange problem while implementing some kind of thread-pool using std::future's.

I have list of executers declared as class member :

```
std::vector<std::future<void>> _executers;
```

I do initialization like this :

```
for (auto& executer : _executers)
    {
        executer = std::async(std::launch::async, [this]()
        {
            try
            {
                for (;;)
                {
                    if (_is_stopping.load())
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    // some long running routine
                }
            }
            catch (std::exception& ex)
            {
            }
            catch (...)
            {
            }
        });
    }
```

In class dtor, I just invoke :

```
_is_stopping.store(true);
```

that should stop for(;;) loop and make future routine return.

But unfortunately, I'm getting a hang while class dtor is invoked and attempting to cleanup std::vector. Backtrace :

```
ntdll.dll!NtWaitForAlertByThreadId() + 20 bytes Unknown
ntdll.dll!RtlSleepConditionVariableSRW() + 250 bytes    Unknown
KernelBase.dll!SleepConditionVariableSRW() + 50 bytes   Unknown
msvcp140.dll!std::_Syserror_map() + 552 bytes   Unknown
msvcp140.dll!_Cnd_timedwait() + 84 bytes    Unknown
DBase.dll!std::_Associated_state<int>::_Wait() Line 306 C++
DBase.dll!std::_Task_async_state<void,0>::~_Task_async_state<void,0>() Line 914 C++
DBase.dll!std::_Task_async_state<void,0>::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)    C++
DBase.dll!std::_Destroy_range<std::allocator<std::future<void> >,std::future<void> * __ptr64>(std::future<void> * _First, std::future<void> * _Last, std::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<std::future<void> > > & _Al) Line 1118 C++>
DBase.dll!DSplunkMsgDevice::Impl::~Impl() Line 191  C++
DBase.dll!std::_Ref_count<DSplunkMsgDevice>::_Destroy() Line 153    C++
DBase.dll!boost::fusion::vector_data4<...>()    C++
ucrtbase.dll!qsort_s() + 1267 bytes Unknown
ucrtbase.dll!_register_onexit_function() + 231 bytes    Unknown
ucrtbase.dll!_execute_onexit_table() + 62 bytes Unknown
DBase.dll!dllmain_crt_process_detach(const bool is_terminating) Line 109    C++
DBase.dll!dllmain_dispatch(HINSTANCE__ * const instance, const unsigned long reason, void * const reserved) Line 207    C++
ntdll.dll!RtlDeactivateActivationContextUnsafeFast() + 435 bytes    Unknown
ntdll.dll!LdrShutdownProcess() + 293 bytes  Unknown
ntdll.dll!RtlExitUserProcess() + 180 bytes  Unknown
kernel32.dll!ExitProcess() + 10 bytes   Unknown
ucrtbase.dll!exit() + 244 bytes Unknown
ucrtbase.dll!exit() + 123 bytes Unknown
DIAControlService.exe!__scrt_common_main_seh() Line 262 C++
kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk() + 20 bytes   Unknown
ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart() + 33 bytes   Unknown
```

Compiler/toolset : VS2015, 14.0.25431.01 Update 3

As far as I understand, std::future lamdba should exit after `_is_loading.store(true)` changing std::future status to std::future_status::ready. Thus, wait() call invoked by std::future dtor should return. But that doesn't happen.

Also, I don't understand why only 1 thread (main thread) is running but std::future is waiting for something.

I really apologize but I can't give more code. I would appreciate if anybody would give me hint what is wrong in my understanding how std::future works.

Comment: can't reproduce with [gcc](https://ideone.com/vxsam6) or VS2017 (locally). I don't see anything wrong with what you've posted. perhaps you have other executers than what you've posted?

Comment: It appears this code is in a DLL. You are, effectively, working with threads from inside `DllMain`, under the loader lock - that's guaranteed to end in tears. It would be best if you provide some kind of `Shutdown` function that the client can call before unloading the DLL, and tear down your thread pool in there.

Comment: I have added cleanup routine to app exit-handler and it looks good and as expected. Thanks, @IgorTandetnik. But if considering object destruction, how dll loader/unloader lock can influence object destruction and thread-pool deinitialization ?

Comment: For a DLL, the runtime destroys global variables when the DLL is unloaded - specifically, when `DllMain` is called (or, to be precise `dllmain_dispatch`, which appears to be the DLL entry point routine in the runtime). That's really the only chance it has. But `DllMain` is called under a loader lock (observe `LdrShutdownProcess` on the stack), which means that any attempt to create or terminate a thread will deadlock (since that thread would in turn try to acquire a loader lock and call `DllMain` on all loaded DLLs).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Igor for such detailed answer!